# Asset dynamic subfolder for User Matrix

Tags: matrix, user-profile, assets-field

I need to set an asset field's dynamic subfolder path to the User ID.

The field is within a matrix.

The matrix a field in a User profile.

Setting it to `{currentUser.id}`, `{owner.author.id}`, `{object.author.id}` results in an invalid path message when trying to upload to the asset field.

Comment: I would like to use `{currentUser.uid}` ideally, so the upload location is anonymous to anyone peeking at the asset URL, however it seems `uid` isn't available on the User model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `{{currentUser.id}}` instead of `{currentUser.id}`

The difference is that double curly brace syntax works on the global scope, while single curly brace syntax tries to resolve itself on the current element. [Relevant documentation.](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/assets-fields.html#dynamic-subfolder-paths)

Comment: Fantastic! I did not know the rule about single `{`'s current element scope vs `{{`'s global scope. FYI I have used `{{ currentUser.uid }}` which creates a nice complex subdirectory something like: `/images/a4b4f254-1beb-4110-be97-ab1c7d47f2a0/image.jpg` Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to import assets and save them into their user folders. nothing of the above works... if I use {{currentUser.username}} it'll import the assets to whoever is logged in. {{user.username}} {user.username} does not work {{author.username}} {author.username} does not work as well. isn't there something more specific that will always save it into the users directory. Also if an admin would edit a user it would put it into the wrong directory... I guess I need some help...

Comment: After investigating a little more I found out that you can use {id} or {username} if the asset field is attached to a user. it's much safer than using {{ currentUser.id }}.